# Boolean not correctly updating unless you print it

Tags: java, swing, applet, boolean

So I am making this java applet and I just want to first make sure the key input works correctly before making it more complex. I have no idea why, but when you remove the "System.out.print(needUpdating);" it does not correctly moves the rectangle according to the key input. Could anyone tell me why and how to fix it? This is a total mystery to me.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;    
import javax.swing.JApplet;    

public class firstApplet extends JApplet implements KeyListener, Runnable {
    final int MOVEAMOUNT = 1;       
    boolean needUpdating;       
    int x,y,dx,dy;      
    Thread runner = null;

    public void init() {
        this.setFocusable(true);            
        needUpdating = false;           
        this.requestFocusInWindow();            
        x=0;            
        y=0;            
        dx=0;           
        dy=0;           
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void stop() {            
    }

    public void start() {
        runner = new Thread(this);          
        runner.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("x= "+x+" y = "+y);          
        g.drawRect( x, y, 100, 15 );
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {                        
        int key = e.getKeyCode();           
        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            System.out.println("up");
            dy=MOVEAMOUNT;
        }
        else if (key==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy=-MOVEAMOUNT;
        }
        else if (key==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx=-MOVEAMOUNT;
        }
        else if (key==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx=MOVEAMOUNT;
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        needUpdating = true;            
        System.out.println("needUpdating listening = " +needUpdating);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dx=0;
        dy=0;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {          
    }

    public void processMovement() {
        System.out.println("processing");
        x+=dx;
        y+=dy;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        while(true) {
            System.out.print(needUpdating);             
            if(needUpdating) {
                processMovement();                  
                repaint();                  
                needUpdating=false;
            }           
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to make `needUpdating` field `volatile`: `volatile boolean needUpdating;`

Answer (score 5):

Your code is incorrectly synchronized. Better said, it isn't synchronized at all. However, `System.out.println` is a synchronized method, and on today's typical CPU architectures, entering a synchronized block happens to be implemented as a *memory barrier* at the native code level. This has the effect of making the changes to your boolean visible to other threads.

Conclusion: correctly synchronize your code and the "magical" behavior will disappear.

Comment: I fixed these bug and find out the rectangle goes up when you press down arrow.

Comment: That's not suprising since you decrease `y` in that case, and the coordinate system's origin is the upper left corner.

Answer (score 4):

There are serious issues with this code. First of all you are implementing Runnable for no good reason. Second of all, your run() method is a big busy-wait loop. And thirdly of course the lack of synchronization in your needsUpdating variable.

Instead of using a thread-unsafe needsUpdating variable, you should perform the required operations in the listener methods, and the thread safety issue will disappear since you'll be in the Event Dispatch Thread.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your field `needUpdating` as `volatile`:

`volatile boolean needUpdating;`

This behaviour is defined by infinite loop inside `run()` method: JVM caches value of `needUpdating` field.

**UPD:** I just checked your code: it works fine with `volatile` modifier on field `needUpdating`, so my answer is the solution.

**UPD2:** For clarifying this problem, look at example in Chapter 17 of JLS7: [17.3. Sleep and Yield](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3)